# how to update one table using data from second table

Tags: mysql

I am bit stuck with this one..  what i want is update app_name (first table). It returns no error.. but does nothing...

```
UPDATE tbl_m_app AS tma, tbl_measure AS tm
SET tma.app_name='Ap1' 

WHERE (tm.mesure_id = tma.mesure_id
AND tm.live = 1)
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing about php in the question

Comment: you need more detail here, are you updating simply from a few values, or 'moving' data from one same structured table to another same structured table?

Comment: What i want is to set app_name to an variable (php) which corresponds to only 1 record in second table mesure_id is AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do the same work in more obvious way and without joins

```
UPDATE tbl_m_app AS tma
SET tma.app_name='Ap1'
WHERE tma.mesure_id IN (SELECT tm.mesure_id FROM tbl_measure AS tm WHERE tm.live = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this SQL is fine, it's just not matching any rows.

Check this by using a select with the same where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_measure tm WHERE tm.live=1;
```

0 rows returned, right?

Comment: it returnes some rows, but (mesure_id + live) is only one

Comment: @Hia how about the join condition then; `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_m_app AS tma, tbl_measure AS tm WHERE tm.mesure_id = tma.mesure_id AND tm.live = 1`